# Microsoft Signal R not able to establish connnection in Prodution build with next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

The negotiation URL is not correctly set while initiating Signal R connection in next js PRODUCTION build (using yarn build command). It's works fine with development build (using yarn dev command)

Local build signal R log - Sending negotiation request to given URL while initiating Signalr
[image]

Production build Signal R log- Sending negotiation request is missing the actual URL that is passed while initiating Signalr,
Throws error _app-981b32fff10f13a9.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/register/pre-fetch?negotiateVersion=1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
here negotiation request URL is changed to " http://localhost:3000/register/pre-fetch?negotiateVersion=1" which is a component path from where signal R initiated, this should be: https:/{{SignalrURL}}/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.

[image]

signal.ts file

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
const conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl('SignalrURL',
                        { accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('token') })
                    .withAutomaticReconnect()
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                    .build()
                    .start();
```

---

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@deere/fuel-react": "^3.0.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.14",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.23.0",
    "applicationinsights": "^2.3.6",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.38",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "13.0.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.4",
    "nextjs-redirect": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.6.0",
    "tls": "^0.0.1",
    "v8": "^0.1.0"
  },
```